# Can't access my website through ip. Is something wrong with my httpd settings?

Tags: apache2, centos, virtualhost

I just set up a fresh apache/mysql install on CentOS on remote server.
Right now I just want to be able to access my server through ip on my server

let's say the ip is **64.123.myip.whatever**

Here is my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf setting

```
### Section 2: 'Main' server configuration
ServerName  64.123.myip.whatever:80

### Section 3: Virtual Hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
    ServerName 64.123.myip.whatever
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart my apache, try to access this server and I get this error in the browser

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 64.123.myip.whatever
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.  First... do you literally mean IP address?  If so then putting that into Chrome is going to actually go right to that address.  The odds of that random IP address actually hosting a webserver is fairly remote, hence the error.  ServerName cannot be an IP address.  If you instead mean you're trying to use a ServerName of "64.123.myip.whatever", then you must add a host entry that directs all traffic for "64.123.myip.whatever" to the IP address of your web server (presumably 127.0.0.1).

Comment: Yes I literally mean IP address. It's an external one. Yes I am trying to go to the right external ip address that is my dedicated host and where apache runs.

Comment: Can you ping the IP ?  Telnet the IP on port 80 and get a response ?  Silly question, but are you sure httpd is running ?  No firewall or other network infrastructural reason impediments in place ?

Comment: yes I can ping the ip, httpd is running, it's a dedicated server.. Can't tellnet to port 80.. 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host 
Telnet just might not be installed on the machine

Comment: That would be the issue (as long as you have telnet on your local computer, that should give you a positive response).  Something is blocking your traffic to that port.  Could your server be setup with ipchains or something similar?

Comment: Maybe telnet is just not running

Comment: telnet is not a service.  It is a generic connection utility.  If it cannot connect to your IP on port 80, then traffic is not getting to the http daemon.

Comment: Here's a link describing the use of telnet in testing http: [Testing HTTP with Telnet](http://www.esqsoft.com/examples/troubleshooting-http-using-telnet.htm)

Comment: As soon as I did  service iptables stop it started to work. Is that safe to have iptables completely stopped?

Comment: Ideally you want to tell iptables to allow web traffic as opposed to shutting it down completely. That is a pretty easy to find procedure both on google and this site.